# Why is @use not compiling in sass?

Tags: css, sass, forward

I am trying to replace @import with @use but the latter does not compile correctly.

My sass file:

```
  @use 'src/_list';
```

result I expect:

```
  .list-reset {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   list-style: none;
  }
```

result I get:

```
  @use 'src/_list';
```

Comment: Hey, check for two things. First: are you using Dart-Sass [1.23.0+] or you using Lib- or Ruby-Sass, which do not support `@use` yet and likely won't ever. If so: try to remove the underscore before 'list' (`@use 'src/list';`) and make sure you are using `@use` before any rules other than `@forward`. https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use

Comment: May I ask why you are you replacing `@import` with `@use` ?

Comment: The official SASS docs are discouraging the use of `@import` in favour of `@use` instead. https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import